# How can I pass an alias value to a bazel function?

Tags: bazel, starlark, skylark

I have the following alias defined in a BUILD file:

```
alias(
    name = "platform",
    actual = select({
        ":macos_x86_64": "macos_x86_64",
        ":linux_x86_64": "linux_x86_64",
        ":linux_aarch64": "linux_aarch64",
    }),
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

How can I pass the "actual" string to a function like this?

```
def myFunction(platform): ...
```

I am trying the most naive thing and it does not understand that it's an alias, not a string:

```
myFunction("//bazel/config:platform")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`def myFunction` creates a [macro](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/skylark/macros.html), not a [rule](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/skylark/rules.html). Macros can't access the values of a `select`, only add other selects to it and pass it to rules. Another way to think about the difference: there are very few things a macro can do which can't be done directly in a BUILD file.

Also, [alias.actual](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/be/general.html#alias.actual) is a `Label`. Even when you pass it to a rule, the values need to be valid labels, and will be handled as such. You can use [Label.name](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/skylark/lib/Label.html#name) to get the name back though.